# Activation record of function and machine commands for freeing arguments from stack

Tags: c, assembly, pascal

I got question in a class. The question says that in C, the caller function is responsible for removing arguments from stack after returning from callee, against Pascal in which the callee responsible for removing the arguments from stack. the question says that the way Pascal removes the arguments is little bit more efficient than the C does, and we were asked why it is. We were given clue - think about machine commands for returning from a function. So I thinked - and as far as I know, in assembly you can change the stack pointer to point to first argument that was inserted to stack in prepare to function activation. So if it is like this, neither C nor Pascal more efficient. Is it?

Comment: No, it is only a question of implementation.

Comment: There's no "stack frame" in C.

Comment: All other things being equal, the overall code size tends to be smaller when Pascal convention is used because when C is used the code to remove arguments is repeated at every call site whereas with Pascal it is only present once, within the routine.

Comment: On the contrary, C can be more efficient because, when calling many functions, clearing their parameters from the stack can be postponed to after the last one, allowing it to be done with only one `add` instruction (the gcc performs this optimization).

Comment: @ArthurLaks: Interesting. I was not aware of that. A bit esoteric, I know, but that will increase the stack memory consumption, no?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I guess that it is a trade-off of consuming for memory for efficiency.

Comment: The efficiency gain is that the code to remove stuff from the stack is only coded once, inside the routine, instead of each time again, when the caller must remove it.

Comment: IOW, efficiency is not just speed.

Answer (score 1):

What they are trying to get at is probably that x86 has a specialized `RET x` instruction which while returning also removes `x` bytes of arguments from the stack. Obviously this may be different on other architectures, where even the calling conventions may differ.

Note that if your function uses local variables, you can fold the function arguments into them so using C calling convention is then the same speed, if not faster.

Comment: So what is the meaning of remove? isn't it just decrementing the SP to point to the cell of the first argument? why do you have to remove the data, it just stays in stack as junk values, isn't it?